# Gradle Checkstyle plugin is incompatible with Google Checks by default

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle

**Please note:** I created [this GitHub project to help you exactly produce the issue](https://github.com/bitbythecron/test-gradle-checkstyle).

---

Java 8 and Gradle 4.6 here. If you create a new Java Gradle project via `gradle init --type java-library` and then the Gradle Checkstyle plugin to it, and configure that plugin to use [Google's Checkstyle XML](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml) it will fail right out of the box:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

dependencies {
    testCompile(
        'junit:junit:4.12'
    )
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

checkstyle {
    // Go to the Google Checks link above and paste its
    // contents into checkstyle.xml
    config = rootProject.resources.text.fromFile('buildConfig/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml')
}
```

With that config, running `./gradle clean build` produces:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':checkstyleMain'.
> Unable to create a Checker: configLocation {/Users/myuser/workspace/test-gradle-checkstyle/buildConfig/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml}, classpath {/Users/myuser/workspace/test-gradle-checkstyle/build/classes/java/main:/Users/myuser/workspace/test-gradle-checkstyle/build/resources/main}.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
$ pwd
/Users/myuser/workspace/test-gradle-checkstyle
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/myuser/workspace/test-gradle-checkstyle/.git/
```

**I'm wondering why?!**

---

**Edit (for future Googlers):**

Using `--stacktrace`, the actual error is

```
cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Token "METHOD_REF" was not found in Acceptable tokens list in check com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.whitespace.SeparatorWrapCheck
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently Gradle uses an old version of CheckStyle - but there is a way to solve this!

First, I'd suggest that when you encounter issues in your build, use the `--stacktrace` or `-S` to see the actual failure, by using it you'll see exactly what is failing:

```
cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Token "METHOD_REF" was not found in Acceptable tokens list in check com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.whitespace.SeparatorWrapCheck
```

This is because Gradle 4.6 uses CheckStyle 6.19, which is quite old by now (latest is 8.11)
Upgrading the configuration to use latest solves this issue:

```
checkstyle {
    config = rootProject.resources.text.fromFile('buildConfig/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml')
    toolVersion '8.11'
}
```

The result is:

```
> Task :checkstyleMain
[ant:checkstyle] [WARN] /.../test-gradle-checkstyle/src/main/java/Library.java:5: 'method def modifier' has incorrect indentation level 4, expected level should be 2. [Indentation]
[ant:checkstyle] [WARN] /.../test-gradle-checkstyle/src/main/java/Library.java:6: 'method def' child has incorrect indentation level 8, expected level should be 4. [Indentation]
[ant:checkstyle] [WARN] /.../test-gradle-checkstyle/src/main/java/Library.java:7: 'method def rcurly' has incorrect indentation level 4, expected level should be 2. [Indentation]

> Task :checkstyleTest
[ant:checkstyle] [WARN] /.../test-gradle-checkstyle/src/test/java/LibraryTest.java:5: 'import' should be separated from previous statement. [EmptyLineSeparator]
[ant:checkstyle] [WARN] /.../test-gradle-checkstyle/src/test/java/LibraryTest.java:5: Import statement for 'org.junit.Assert.*' is in the wrong order. Should be in the 'STATIC' group, expecting not assigned imports on this line. [CustomImportOrder]
[ant:checkstyle] [WARN] /.../test-gradle-checkstyle/src/test/java/LibraryTest.java:5: Using the '.*' form of import should be avoided - org.junit.Assert.*. [AvoidStarImport]
[ant:checkstyle] [WARN] /.../test-gradle-checkstyle/src/test/java/LibraryTest.java:8: 'method def modifier' has incorrect indentation level 4, expected level should be 2. [Indentation]
[ant:checkstyle] [WARN] /.../test-gradle-checkstyle/src/test/java/LibraryTest.java:9: 'method def' child has incorrect indentation level 8, expected level should be 4. [Indentation]
[ant:checkstyle] [WARN] /.../test-gradle-checkstyle/src/test/java/LibraryTest.java:10: 'method def' child has incorrect indentation level 8, expected level should be 4. [Indentation]
[ant:checkstyle] [WARN] /.../test-gradle-checkstyle/src/test/java/LibraryTest.java:11: 'method def rcurly' has incorrect indentation level 4, expected level should be 2. [Indentation]


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 9s
7 actionable tasks: 7 executed
```

There are several bugs open on this issue both in the Gradle project and the CheckStyle project

Comment: Thanks @Boaz (+1) - just one quick followup: how did you know to use version 8.11? I know Checkstyle is up to 8.11 but I couldn't find anything in the Gradle documentation indicating it currently supported the latest (8.11) version of Checkstyle yet...thanks again!

Comment: Frankly? I tried the recommended version I've seen in the checkstyle github (8.2), I've seen that the METHOD_REF problem was resolved and instead there was a different issue related to a customer checker defined in the XML. I've decided to test it with the latest and indeed it worked. As you can see, Gradle supports any version of checkstyle, just not OOB, the OOB version is way to old to be relevant in a post Java 8 world. Think of Gradle as a generic runner, checkstyle does the heavy-lifting.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup If my answer indeed solved the issue, please consider accepting it (the V sign under the score)

Comment: Isn't checkstyle use google style guides by default?